# How to call a vector function and return a vector from a function

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to shift the elements of a vector to the side by `k` number of times. I have the code ready, however, I have problems calling and returning the function which is of type vector. Please take a look at my code and give me the correct guidance as to what to put where I have commented with question marks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int k);//function to shift the vector elements to the right k times

int main()
{
    int no;// number of times to shift the vector

    vector<int> arr;// array to be shifted

    //initializing vectors
    arr.push_back(1);
    arr.push_back(2);
    arr.push_back(3);
    arr.push_back(4);
    cout<<"write the no of times to rotate elements: "<<endl;
    cin>>no;

    solution(arr, no)//?????? dont know how to call the function

    return 0;
}


vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int k){

    int times=(k%A.size());// number of times to be shifted 

    int count=0;


    //while loop to shift times number of TIMES
    while(count<=times){

        for(int i=0; i<A.size();i++)// FOR LOOP TO SHIFT EACH ELEMENT TO THE SIDE ONCE
        {
            if(A[i]!=A[(A.size()-1)])
                A[i]=A[i+1];
            else
                A[i]=A[i-(A.size()-1)];
            count++;
        }

        return A; // ??? how do I return the value of the vector to the main program?
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a reference so why are you returning it?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Compiling error? Error in the result?

Comment: `return A` is inside the `while` loop, put it outside. Or better remove the return and change the return type of the function to `void`.

Comment: You already have the value as it was past as a non-const reference. 

You do not need to return it and in fact you should not return it the way you do since it copies the vector it is time consuming. 

Also, your algorithms is O(k*n) [for k<n] while an O(n) solution can easily be achieved.

Comment: *I am writing a program to shift the elements of a vector to the side by k number of times* -- You are reinventing the wheel.  The `std::rotate` function already does this.

Comment: @Ventu I am using an online C++ compiler, no error message, it  just asks for the number of times i want the the elements to be shifted, after that it doesn't give the shifted vector output.

Comment: @KarstenKoop thanks for the observation that was a mistake, changed it but still didn't work. and I am following specifications given by by the online practice questions, which requires the function to be of a return type.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie It is a practice question, I am relatively new to programming, that's why i'm trying to work it out myself I could use the rotate function. Thanks for the tip tho.